# How do i replace a value displayed 0.00 to '-' hyphen in Visualbasic 6.0

Tags: vb6

How do i replace a value displayed  0.00 to '-' hyphen  in Visualbasic 6.0
e.g I have a line of code below that dispalys out but some records are 0.00, i wanted to present them as blank or with a '-'

```
 .PDFTextOut FormatNumber(IIf(IsNull(adRst![Outstanding Portofolio]), Empty, adRst![Outstanding Portofolio]), 2, True, True, True), 180, Str(xCtR)
```

Comment: can't you format the string using VB6 built-in FORMAT function? Or use the REPLACE function to remove what you don't want and put in the hyphen or minus sign?

Comment: I want to replace them with a hyphen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Format$() function accepts a 3-part formatting string delimited by ";" characters.  Example:

```
Dim Expression As Single
Dim Formatted As String

Expression = 0
Formatted = Format$(Expression, "0.00;-0.00;\-")
MsgBox Formatted
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the VB6 Replace function.

`Replace$(expression, find, replacewith[, start[, count[, compare]]])`

see [Visual Basic 6 String Functions](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-string-functions)

try something like this:

```
sNewStr=REPLACE(sOldStr, "0.00", "-")
```

where `sOldStr` is the string with the *0.00* and `sNewStr` is the output

Comment: `2000.00` becomes `200-`. `Replace()` is not suitable for this.